# Integration involving double exponential function

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function

I am trying to solve the following integral but not getting it properly. Also when I had used MATHEMATICA, it is unable to solve it. Further, I tried table of integral book, but couldn't find the closed form expression.

$\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\left[\text{exp}{\left(-\frac{z}{c\sigma_x^2}\right)}\cdot\left(1-\text{exp}{\left(-\frac{z}{d\sigma_q^2}\right)}\right)\right]^L}{(1+z)}\text{d}z$

where $c,d,L$ are constants.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that the problem is
$$I_L=\int_0^\infty \frac{\Big[e^{-a z} \left(1-e^{-b z}\right)\Big]^L}{z+1}dz.$$ Using the binomial theorem, rewrite the numerator as
$$e^{-aL z}\sum_{n=0}^L (-1)^n \binom{L}{n}e^{-n b z}=\sum_{n=0}^L (-1)^n \binom{L}{n}e^{-(a L+b n)z}.$$ Now use the fact that
$$J_k=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-k z}}{z+1} dz=-e^k \,\text{Ei}(-k).$$

Comment: Ok...will explore your answer by plotting in MATLAB.....Thanks once again..